# How do I check my Code is working fine using Audience Network?

Tags: google-dfp, facebook-audience-network

I am using audience Network for my website. But I don't know how to Verify this code. So Please check the below URL and Let me know.

http://www.maalaimalar.com/adcheck.html

Comment: using ?pbjs_debug=true the console notify an error: ERROR: valid placementids are required

Comment: why it could be occurred??